# Why is cider-jack-in hanging in emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

I'm working through [the following tutorial on Clojure](http://www.braveclojure.com/basic-emacs/). I've just installed both Emacs and Leiningen. If invoked separately, both work. However, when I am trying to invoke `cider-jack-in`, as described in the tutorial:

> Using Emacs, open the file clojure-noob/src/clojure_noob/core.clj,
>   which you created in Chapter 1. Next, use M-x cider-jack-in. This
>   starts the REPL and creates a new buffer where you can interact with
>   it.

that hangs forever after the last message:

```
Starting nREPL server via lein repl :headless...
You can run the command `cider-jack-in' with C-c M-j
Starting nREPL server via lein repl :headless...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: To solve the problem, I upgraded leiningen from 1.7 (that's what apt-get installed) to 2.6.1.

Comment: Did you try doing `lein repl` from the console? Does it work?

Comment: @OlegTheCat Yes lein did run from the command line, and right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently cider changed so you no longer need to add things to ~/.lein/profiles.clj to install cider-nrepl and clj-refactor. Cider will take care of that now. You should remove that part from your config.

In general for these situations it help to run lein from the command line first and make sure it can actually get the projects dependencies. Most of the times it's sitting there downloading a jar file at 3 bytes per second and not actually stalled. Other times it's failing with SSL/TLS certificate validation problems.

Comment: Nice advice about fixing the config.